# Open Button on Simple Javapad application

Tags: java

I am looking for some help with my open button for a notepad application in java. This is what I have:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Javapad extends JFrame {
  private JMenuBar menuBar;
  private JMenu fileMenu;
  private JMenuItem n, open, save, exit;

  public Javapad() {
    super("Javapad");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
    buildGUI();
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
  }

class MenuListener implements ActionListener {
  private JFileChooser fc;
  private JTextArea area;

  public MenuListener(JTextArea area) {
    fc = new JFileChooser();
    this.area = area;
  }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if(e.getSource() == n) {
      this.area.setText(" ");
    } else if(e.getSource() == open) {
      int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(Javapad.this);
      if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try{

        File f = new File("Users");
        FileReader in = new FileReader(f);
        int size = (int) f.length();
        char data[] = new char[size];  
        in.read(data); 
        in.close(); 
        String s = new String(data); 
        this.area.setText(data); 

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException z){
        }


       }
  } else if(e.getSource() == save) {
      int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(Javapad.this);
      if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        // try to save file
      }
  }
  else if(e.getSource() == exit) {
      System.exit(0); 
  }
}
}

 private void buildGUI() {
Container container = this.getContentPane();

menuBar = new JMenuBar();
container.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);   

fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
menuBar.add(fileMenu);

n = new JMenuItem("New");
fileMenu.add(n);
fileMenu.addSeparator();

open = new JMenuItem("Open");
fileMenu.add(open);
fileMenu.addSeparator();

save = new JMenuItem("Save");
fileMenu.add(save);
fileMenu.addSeparator();

exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
fileMenu.add(exit);

JTextArea edit = new JTextArea(30,20);
edit.setFont(new Font("Menlo", Font.PLAIN, 14));

JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(edit);
sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 100));
container.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

MenuListener ml = new MenuListener(edit);
n.addActionListener(ml);
open.addActionListener(ml);
save.addActionListener(ml);
exit.addActionListener(ml);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
Javapad jp = new Javapad();
 }
 }
```

Comment: You just posted query and code. Can you please tell what and where is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Currently getting this error...   Javapad.java:44: error: incompatible types: char[] cannot be converted to String
            this.area.setText(data);

Comment: @I31, `Currently getting this error...` - and you were given the better way to read the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's for school and we have to do it a certain way, I know theres much better ways to do it, but I need this way to work

Comment: Please properly format your code. Also refer to http://www.sscce.org for a good explanation regarding how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file into a `JTextArea` then you can just use the `read(...)` method of the `JTextArea`:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader( new File(...) );
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
textArea.read( br, null );
br.close();
```

So you get the `File` from the `JFileChooser` and then just read the file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's just a small typo in these lines:

```
char data[] = new char[size];  
in.read(data); 
in.close(); 
String s = new String(data); 
this.area.setText(data);
```

`area.setText()` needs to be passed a string (s) rather than an array of chars (data). Just change the last line to this:

```
this.area.setText(s);
```

Comment: This is the error Im currently getting Javapad.java:44: error: incompatible types: char[] cannot be converted to String
            this.area.setText(data);